# How to simulate a new variable in regression analysis

Tags: regression, simulation

Suppose my current regression model is $y=\beta_0+\beta_1x_1+\beta_2x_2$
Now I want to add a new variable $x_3$ (normally distributed). All I know is $x_3$'s mean and standard deviation.

Is it a sound methodology to randomly generate $x_3$, according to its mean and sd, and include it in the regression (and maybe bootstrap it a few hundred times)?

Comment: How does that $x_3$ variable relate to the response variable $y$? Just putting in a noise variable is unlikely to help you accomplish what you hope to do.

Comment: qualitative research shows x3 impacts y. But my data doesn't have x3

Comment: But then the order of the $x_3$ values (the $y$-values to which they correspond) matters much more than the distribution of $x_3$ marginally, whether $x_3$ is marginally normal or not. $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and $\{2,1,4,5,3\}$ have the same distribution, but those will have different effects in a regression, since each value will correspond to a different $y$-value. $\text{//}$ When we make an assumption about normality in regression, that is about the error term, not the predictor variables. In fact, it is common for predictor variables to be non-normal, even discrete.

Comment: You can learn absolutely nothing about $y$ by introducing random data like $x_3$!

Answer (score 5):

The only way to learn about $x_3$ is to collect data about it. Simulating random data is circular because it only tells you information about your randomization procedure.

In particular, you'll need to know about the tuples $(y, x_1, x_2, x_3)$, that is, how all of your $x$s vary with respect to the $y$ for each observational unit.

Answer (score 0):

There are routines for generating random Normal deviates, which could be employed to add a noise variable to a regression model.

While adding such a variable has no value from the point of prediction, it can actually, per sources, unfortunately introduce bias into the regression model.

Further, the amount of the bias can be demonstrated to be proportional to the magnitude of a constructed auxiliary variable (see, for example, discussion in [Some Notes on Misspecification in Multiple Regressions](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00031305.1971.10477302?src=recsys)).

As such, while there is seemingly no potential value in investigating the impact of introducing a so-called 'irrelevant variable' in the regression analysis, it could nevertheless provide some insights on conceivable bias arising from model misspecification.

Comment: Thanks! You are a beacon of hope.